# Why the next button of facebook marketplace is grayed out for a lifetime?

Tags: python, selenium, facebook, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to make automation bot to post properties on Facebook marketplace using python + selenium webdriver.
But next button is not clickable although I input all of information including both of required and optional fields.

I am not sure FB bot detection criteria..
Please help me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.